# Is there a 'contains' functionality on a collection property of a domain object for createCriteria?

Tags: grails, createcriteria

I have an Auction domain object and a User domain object.  An Auction `hasMany` Users.

What I'd like to do, using `createCriteria`, is something like this:

```
def c = Auction.createCriteria()
def l = c.list (max: maxVar, offset: offsetVar) {
    contains("users", thisUser)
}
```

Though, `contains` is not in the list of acceptable nodes: [createCriteria description page](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html%20%22).

Is there any way to implement this functionality?

To be clear, is there a way to have the criteria be that a specified User object is contained within a collection property of the Auction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
def l = c.list (max: maxVar, offset: offsetVar) {
    users {
        idEq(thisUser.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice... it's not obvious that you can do this, since the syntax looks like "must have a *users* object whose id is this", as opposed to "must have a users collection which contains an object with this id".