# Is there a 'contains' functionality on a collection of ObjectId property of a domain object for withCriteria?

Tags: mongodb, grails, createcriteria

I have a Subscription domain object which has a List of ObjectId as one of its properties, say 'subscribed'. I'm on Grails 2.1.2 and MongoDB.

```
class Subscription {
    ObjectId id
    List<ObjectId> subscribers = [] as List<ObjectId>

    static mapWith = "mongo"
}
```

I'm looking for something like this

```
def c = Subscription.withCriteria {
    contains("subscribers", specificId)
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I'm aware of [this very same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475009) but provided answer to that question doesn't work for a property which is of type List of ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

See [grails criteria docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html). Try to use like this:

```
def c = Subscription.withCriteria {
    subscribers{
        eq("id",specificId)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, following runtime error is thrown : 
Join queries are not supported by MongoDB. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Join queries are not supported by MongoDB
    Line | Method
->>  117 | handle             in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.query.MongoQuery$2

Comment: You'd better say that it's mongo before (=

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll edit the question! See my last edit of question in which Subscription class and subscribers property are added.