# Is there a 'does not contains' functionality on a collection property of a domain object for createCriteria?

Tags: grails, hql, createcriteria

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475009/is-there-a-contains-functionality-on-a-collection-property-of-a-domain-object). But I want a **does not contain** functionality.

Like I have a Post domain. A Post **hasMany** User.
What I'd like to do, using createCriteria, is something like this:

```
def c = Post.createCriteria()
def l = c.list (max: maxVar) {
    notContains("users", thisUser)
}
```

I tried using **ne** But no luck.

```
def l = c.list (max: maxVar) {
    users {
        ne('id', thisUser.id)
    }
}
```

To be clear, how can I get list of all the Post whose users field which is a collection does not contain **thisUser** ?

Comment: what Grails version do you use?

Comment: try the negative form of the 'in' predicate, e.g. `not {'in'("age",[18..65])}`

Comment: I am using grails 2.3.8

Comment: I tried `not {eq('id', user.id)}` , didn't work, gave same result as **ne**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HQL` for this

```
List<Post> posts = Post.executeQuery("select distinct p from Post p where :myUser not member of p.users", [myUser: user, max: maxVar])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c.list (max: maxVar) { not { 'in'("users", thisUser) }}
```

Will return a list without thisUser. This works for grails version 2.*. You may need to override .equals for your User class.

There are also many other ways to this such as using .find. Please see this link http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections

Comment: Added `@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return obj instanceof User && (id == obj.id)
}` and this method gave error **Message: could not execute query**

Comment: `Post.findAll{usersInterested.find{user}}` gave error **Message: 0**

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get a conventional solution to it, but I solved this problem using two separate queries.

First I got all the **Posts** whose **users** contain **thisUser** using

`users {
        eq('id', thisUser.id)
    }`

Then I got max number of Post whose id does not match any of the id from above.

`Post.findAllByIdNotInList(usersList.id, [max:15])`

where **usersList** is result from first query

P.S. : Please answer if anyone has a better solution. Thanks