# Criteria to get all Person's, who doesnt own a Ford car

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain class `Person`, as below

```
class Person {
   static hasMany=[cars:Car]
}
```

Now, i want fetch all `Person`, **who doesn't own a 'Ford' car**. The problem with below criteria is that, it fetches 'Person' with two cars, out of which one is 'Ford'.

```
List promotions = Person.createCriteria().list(  ) {
    cars {
        ne(‘name’, ‘Ford’)
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a 'does not contains' functionality on a collection property of a domain object for createCriteria?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180418/is-there-a-does-not-contains-functionality-on-a-collection-property-of-a-domai)

Comment: Is there a criteria based solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
List promotions = Person.createCriteria().list(  ) {       
 sqlRestriction " id not in (select person_id from car where 'Ford' = name );"
}
```